# impossible to read a csv file ith pyspark

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I try to read a csv file using pyspark with this pyspark code :

```
tr_df = spark.read.csv("/data/file.csv",
                       header=True, inferSchema=True
                      )
tr_df.head(5)
```

But I get this error :

> ```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-53-03432bbf269d> in <module>
> ----> 1 tr_df.head(5)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py
> ```
>
> in head(self, n)
>          1250             rs = self.head(1)
>          1251             return rs[0] if rs else None
>       -> 1252         return self.take(n)
>          1253 
>          1254     @ignore_unicode_prefix
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py
> ```
>
> in take(self, num)
>           569         [Row(age=2, name=u'Alice'), Row(age=5, name=u'Bob')]
>           570         """
>       --> 571         return self.limit(num).collect()
>           572 
>           573     @since(1.3)
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py
> ```
>
> in collect(self)
>           532         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
>           533             sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
>       --> 534         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
>           535 
>           536     @ignore_unicode_prefix
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py
> ```
>
> in load_stream(self, stream)
>           145         while True:
>           146             try:
>       --> 147                 yield self._read_with_length(stream)
>           148             except EOFError:
>           149                 return
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py
> ```
>
> in _read_with_length(self, stream)
>           170         if len(obj) < length:
>           171             raise EOFError
>       --> 172         return self.loads(obj)
>           173 
>           174     def dumps(self, obj):
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py
> ```
>
> in loads(self, obj, encoding)
>           578     if sys.version >= '3':
>           579         def loads(self, obj, encoding="bytes"):
>       --> 580             return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
>           581     else:
>           582         def loads(self, obj, encoding=None):
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py
> ```
>
> in _parse_datatype_json_string(json_string)
>           867     >>> check_datatype(complex_maptype)
>           868     """
>       --> 869     return _parse_datatype_json_value(json.loads(json_string))
>           870 
>           871
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py
> ```
>
> in _parse_datatype_json_value(json_value)
>           884         tpe = json_value["type"]
>           885         if tpe in _all_complex_types:
>       --> 886             return _all_complex_types[tpe].fromJson(json_value)
>           887         elif tpe == 'udt':
>           888             return UserDefinedType.fromJson(json_value)
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py
> ```
>
> in fromJson(cls, json)
>           575     @classmethod
>           576     def fromJson(cls, json):
>       --> 577         return StructType([StructField.fromJson(f) for f in json["fields"]])
>           578 
>           579     def fieldNames(self):
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py
> ```
>
> in (.0)
>           575     @classmethod
>           576     def fromJson(cls, json):
>       --> 577         return StructType([StructField.fromJson(f) for f in json["fields"]])
>           578 
>           579     def fieldNames(self):
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py
> ```
>
> in fromJson(cls, json)
>           432     def fromJson(cls, json):
>           433         return StructField(json["name"],
>       --> 434                            _parse_datatype_json_value(json["type"]),
>           435                            json["nullable"],
>           436                            json["metadata"])
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/types.py
> ```
>
> in _parse_datatype_json_value(json_value)
>           880             return DecimalType(int(m.group(1)), int(m.group(2)))
>           881         else:
>       --> 882             raise ValueError("Could not parse datatype: %s" % json_value)
>           883     else:
>           884         tpe = json_value["type"]
>
> ```
> ValueError: Could not parse datatype: decimal(17,-24)
> ```

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is a problem with datatype in one of your columns. Hence its throwing error. Remove inferSchema =True option while reading. After reading the data,try to analayze datatype and make any corrections if needed, then apply your own schema.